# In Jenkins how can I mask the contents of a dynamic variable from output?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a dynamic credential that I am fetching in a script. When I later use that secret it is un-masked in the Jenkins output. How can I tell Jenkins to just mask a particular string dynamically?

```
stage ("Release") {
  steps {
    script {
      withCredentials([
        usernamePassword(
          credentialsId: 'github-app',
          usernameVariable: 'GITHUB_API_ID',
          passwordVariable: 'GITHUB_API_KEY'
        )
      ]) {
        def TOKEN = sh(
          returnStdout: true,
          script: '''#!/bin/bash
            ENCODED_KEY=$(echo -n "$GITHUB_API_KEY" | base64)
            github_app_auth "$GITHUB_API_ID" "$ENCODED_KEY" "$GITHUB_INSTALLATION_ID"
          '''
        ).trim()

        // This function is logging TOKEN unmasked...
        glGithubRelease([
          token:          TOKEN,
          tagName:        VERSION,
          commitish:      COMMIT,
        ])
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the above script I would like to know how to tell Jenkins to mask the local `TOKEN`. I am using `withCredentials` to mask my `GITHUB_API_KEY` and I am using `#!/bin/bash` to mask the contents of `ENCODED_KEY` (by showing no output at all) but the `glGithubRelease` function is 3rd party and it is logging all input parameters and I want to tell Jenkins to mask the `TOKEN` string as if its a credential.